# Python (2.*) Tkinter - Advanced Event Handling Formatting

Tags: python, tkinter, event-handling

I'm writing a test program to detect mouse motion within a Tkinter Window using Python 2.*. I can create the necessary widgets and bind the appropriate event handler function to the root widget as needed:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class App:

   def __init__(self, master=None):
      self.root = master
      self.frame = tk.Frame(master)
      self.frame.pack()
      self.create_widgets()
      self.setup_handlers()

   def create_widgets(self):
      ...

   def setup_handlers(self):
      self.root.bind('<Motion>', self.update)   # This is the line I wish to look at

   def update(self, event):
      ...

root = tk.Tk()
app = App(master=root)
root.mainloop()
```

What I want to do now is be able to activate the event handler with a combined input. I want to be able, for instance, to only activate the event handler when I move the mouse with the 'r' key held down. What event string would I need for this? Where can I find a full rundown on the event-string formatting for binding event handlers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the combined event handling, you can do something like:

```
class App:
  holding = False
  def __init__(self, master):
    self.root = master
    self.root.bind("<KeyPress>", self.holdkey)
    self.root.bind("<KeyRelease>", self.releasekey)

  def holdkey(self, e):
    if e.char == "r" and not self.holding:
      self.root.bind("<Motion>", self.combined_update)
      self.holding = True

  def releasekey(self, e):
    if e.char == "r" and self.holding:
      self.root.unbind("<Motion>")
      self.holding = False

  def combined_update(self, e):
    # Event handling for the combined event.
    print ("yo")
```

This will "probably" work.

Comment: That works well. Out of curiosity, though, do you happen to know where I can find the Binding Strings? I've searched, and I've found sites that provide commonly used ones, but I'm wondering where I can find ALL of them (for future reference...)

Comment: I guess what I really want to know is if there is support for combining event binding strings. Because it sounds like performing nested binding statements would get pretty complicated after a while (especially if we have different `<Motion>` event handlings depending on the depressed key from `<KeyPress>` handler). I understand that TK supports user-defined, named 'Virtual Events'. Does Tkinter support that in any way?

Comment: I understand what you trying to achieve, just wanna put it out here, in case, you can unbind a specific event , just need to assign the callback to a variable.if you do `var = root.bind("<Motion>", func)`, you can unbind this one specifically by doing `root.unbind("Motion", var)`

Comment: @S.Gamgee: there is support for combining events, but I'm not sure if combining key and mouse events works the way you expect. For example, there is no event sequence for "holding a button" -- you can bind on a press, or on a release, but not on a hold. Plus, different hardware systems handle long presses differently (some do what you expect and send a single press and release event, some keyboards send a steady stream of press/release pairs) FWIW, the canonical description of tkinter events is in the tcl/tk documentation: http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/bind.htm